# React-VR set camera position when replacing Pano

Tags: javascript, three.js, react-360

I'm new with react-vr and want to make a tour app. There I update the `Pano` pictures. When I set a new picture the camera/scene is at the same position as  before loading the new picture.

Here is a part of the code:

```
 render() {
if (!this.state.data) {
  return null;
}

const locationId = this.state.locationId;
const isLoading = this.state.nextLocationId !== this.state.locationId;

return (

    <View>
      <Pano
        style={{
          position: 'absolute'
           }}
        onLoad={() => {
          this.setState({
          locationId: this.state.nextLocationId
          });
        }}
        source={asset(this.state.data.photos360[this.state.nextLocationId].uri)}
      />

      {tooltips && tooltips.map((tooltip, index) => {
        return(
          <NavButton
            key={index}
            isLoading={isLoading}
            onInput={() => {
                    this.setState({
                        nextLocationId: tooltip.linkedPhoto360Id});
            }}
            source={asset(this.state.data.nav_icon)}
            textLabel={tooltip.text}
            rotateY={(tooltip.rotationY && tooltip.rotationY) || 0}
            rotateX={(tooltip.rotationX && tooltip.rotationX) || 0}
            translateZ={(tooltip.translateZ && tooltip.translateZ) || this.translateZ}
          />
        );
      })}
    </View>

);}
```

Now I want to set the camera position or transform the picture so that I start at a certain position on the picture.

I have found no possibility to get the actual camera position in react-vr or to set the camera position.

What would be the best way to do this?
Thanks for help

Comment: It sounds like you just want to rotate your pano, so that it is looking a certain direction when it loads. If that's what's up you can set rotation with the style attribute of the pano.

Comment: I have tried to rotate the pano but then I need to know the actual rotation of the camera. Because if the user rotated by 180° and I replace the pano, the rotation of the camera is still at 180°. So I somehow have to get the rotaion of the camera and set the rotation of the pano to this value I think. But I have no idea how to get the rotation.

Comment: Gotcha - You are looking for VRHeadModel: https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/vrheadmodel.html

Comment: Oh yeah thanks that's the API I was looking for :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution and want to post it here if other people have a similar problem.

```
render() {
//if the pano source changes it renders 
//it gets the position in x and y axis in ° via the VrHeadModel
const rotationY=VrHeadModel.yawPitchRoll()[1]+offestY;
const rotationX=VrHeadModel.yawPitchRoll()[0]+offsetX;

return (
  <Pano
        style={{
          position: 'absolute',
            transform:[
             {rotateY: rotationY},
             {rotateX: rotationX},
             ]
        }}
        source={asset("photo.png")}
   />
 );
}
```

And import the `VrHeadModel` from react-vr.
So if the the pano changes the new picture is rotated to the actual position of the camera. The camera is set to the same part of the pano when loading a new picture every time .